How to design an abstraction that will allow users to define their own function to perform a particular task, and use that function in my application
I am fairly new to java development and as part of a project I am making a library that needs to connect to different Database based on a clientID, these databases have multiple shards. Furthermore the client is given the liberty to provide their own shard resolution logic which we will use. I have defined an interface which the client will need to implement in their ClientShardLogic class.
My issue comes due to the structure of what we are trying to build, the client will send all their requests to a Query service and the query service will be using the library, I don't know how I will take the client defined class and use it. I was looking at how kafka library for java allows users to define their own partition logic and my surface level understanding was that -> while creating a Producer object we pass the location of the class as a property to the "partitioner.class" and the library will use the class in that location (I may have understood it wrong, sorry). This would work if the client was directly importing and using my library but since they only have contact with the query service I am stumped.
One though I had was that since the clients connection details are already stored on a server from where I will fetch the DB connection details, maybe they could upload their compiled class file as well and i could use that? A simple idea would be to pass the class along with the initial request but I feel that doesn't seem right to do.
I would be thankful if you could provide any inputs on what I can do or any suggestions on something I need to change.
Also if you have any resources I can checkout related to my problem or any design/java websites, that help that would be amazing too.
Thanks.

"I am fairly new to java development". Seriously, then start by learning the basics. This is quite an advanced feature that you are talking about. Without decent enough knowledge of the language, this is not really a good task to take on.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Try reading the Oracle Tutorial Trail on Reflection: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html.  It will explain a lot of the things that you need to know.
